microsoft-identity-web-graphserviceclient How to configure dependency injection for Azure Function (C#) .NET 8?
I created a brand-new C# Azure Function with .NET 8 in VS 2022, added Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient 2.18.1 and tried to configure it with dependency injection. Based on the docs in GitHub, I should only have to add a using statement for Microsoft.Identity.Web and call services.AddMicrosoftGraph(). I added an appsettings.json file with a valid AzureAd section in it. I can configure it manually in my functions class like this:
  var tokenFactory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance();
  tokenFactory.Services.AddMicrosoftGraph(config);
  var serviceProvider = tokenFactory.Build();
  _graphServiceClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<GraphServiceClient>();

But I've been unable to use dependency injection. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
